# Mysql WHERE with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

How to use WHERE clause with a field in table_1 with INNER JOIN to table_2. Something like below.

```
SELECT t1.result, t1.result_date
    FROM outcomes t1 
    WHERE t1.status = 'finished'
    INNER JOIN games t2
      ON t1.game_id = t2.game_id
    WHERE t2.closing_time < NOW();
```

Below are the sample tables:

**games table**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
game_id   name      start_time               closing_time
--------------------------------------------------------
1          aaa     2018-04-25 16:00:45     2018-04-25 16:30:45
2          bbb     2018-04-25 17:00:45     2018-04-25 17:30:45
3          ccc     2018-04-25 18:00:45     2018-04-25 18:30:45
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

**outcomes table**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
id   game_id    result      round    result_date          status
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1      1       2,4,6       1        2018-04-25 16:15:45  finished
2      1       4,5,3       2        2018-04-25 16:35:45  canceled
3      2       1,2,4       1        2018-04-25 17:15:45  finished
4      2       5,2,4       2        2018-04-25 17:30:45  canceled
5      3       1,2,3       1        2018-04-25 18:15:45  finished
6      3       2,2,5       2        2018-04-25 18:30:45  to-be-confirmed
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Assume the current time is 2018-04-25 18:13, my expected output is:

```
2,4,6        2018-04-25 16:15:45
1,2,4        2018-04-25 17:15:45
```

which corresponds to rows with id equal to 1 and 3 respctively from outcomes table

Comment: a Table Sample with the expected Result would be great, Unless you meant to use `ON t1.game_id = t2.game_d AND t2.closing_time < NOW()` without the last `WHERE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can only be one `WHERE` clause, and it has to come after all the `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses. Combine the conditions with `AND`.

```
SELECT t1.result, t1.result_date
FROM outcomes t1 
INNER JOIN games t2
  ON t1.game_id = t2.game_id
WHERE t2.closing_time < NOW())
  AND t1.status = 'finished'
```

Comment: `t2.closing_time < NOW())` could also be in the ON clause.

Comment: @LioraHaydont In general, `ON` should only contain conditions that relate the tables being joined. The exception is `LEFT JOIN`, where you must put restrictions on the second table there.

Comment: Maybe someone would want to join only on `t2` that are already closed, in this case putting the condition in the `ON` would make more sens. Since it's an `INNER JOIN` it doesn't make any difference but it's still a viable syntax that could help other users

Comment: Yes it's allowed, in most cases you can freely move conditions between `ON` and `WHERE`. But I prefer to organize it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got ur question right, but i think you are looking for something like that

```
SELECT t1.result, t1.result_date
        FROM outcomes t1 
        INNER JOIN games t2
          ON t1.game_id = t2.game_id
        WHERE t2.closing_time < NOW() AND t1.status = 'finished';
```

Comment: How is that any different from the other answer?

Comment: The other answer wans't there when I started writing mine. Sorry about that